# "In accordance to the rule" and "in accordance with the rule"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, grammaticality, prepositions, collocation

Is it correct to use the preposition *to* in "in accordance *to* the rules" or does it have to be *with* as in "in accordance *with* the rule"? I have found usage of *with* to be more frequent but have seen a few instances of *to* being used. Also, here on http://grammarist.com/usage/accord-accordance/ it says either *to* or *with* can be used.

Comment: In {accord/agreement/accordance} _with_.  According _to_.

Answer (score 4):

"In accordance **with**" is by far the most used.

"In accordance **to**" is less popular, by a factor of hundreds

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+accordance+with%2Cin+accordance+to&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cin%20accordance%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20accordance%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIn%20accordance%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cin%20accordance%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20accordance%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIn%20accordance%20to%3B%2Cc0